# How can I retrieve an icon from an object/array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openweathermap

I'm currently working on a project where I need to extract an icon from an object or an array. However, I'm encountering difficulties in doing so. My approach involves storing the icon in a variable and then passing it as a prop to another component. Unfortunately, despite following this approach, the functionality isn't working as I anticipated.

This is the error i'm getting in the console: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')" That happend when i implement this code `<img src={props.icon} alt="cloud" />` with out of that works fine

Here is the code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Weather from "./components/Weather";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${search}&appid=1769e69d20183ccd0c32ac3215db1d40&units=metric`
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }, [search]);

  const handleInput = (event) => {
    setSearch(event.target.value);
  };

  let icon = data.weather[0].icon + ".png";

  return (
    <div>
      <Weather icon={icon} inputValue={handleInput} showItems={data} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import "./style/Weather.css";
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css";

function Weather(props) {
  //   const data = [
  //     {
  //       coord: {
  //         lon: -0.1257,
  //         lat: 51.5085,
  //       },
  //       weather: [
  //         {
  //           id: 804,
  //           main: "Clouds",
  //           description: "overcast clouds",
  //           icon: "04d",
  //         },
  //       ],
  //       base: "stations",
  //       main: {
  //         temp: 285.69,
  //         feels_like: 285.19,
  //         temp_min: 284.29,
  //         temp_max: 286.64,
  //         pressure: 1015,
  //         humidity: 84,
  //       },
  //       visibility: 10000,
  //       wind: {
  //         speed: 5.14,
  //         deg: 210,
  //       },
  //       clouds: {
  //         all: 100,
  //       },
  //       dt: 1710850556,
  //       sys: {
  //         type: 2,
  //         id: 2075535,
  //         country: "GB",
  //         sunrise: 1710828286,
  //         sunset: 1710871895,
  //       },
  //       timezone: 0,
  //       id: 2643743,
  //       name: "London",
  //       cod: 200,
  //     },
  //   ];

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="weather-container">
        <input
          onChange={props.inputValue}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter a city name"
        />
        <p>{props.showItems.name}</p>
        <img src={props.icon} alt="cloud" />
        {props.showItems.main && <p>{props.showItems.main.temp.toFixed()}°C</p>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Weather;
```

Comment: In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193) you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: My apologies. I hope it's okey now.

Comment: `data.weather?.[0]`

Comment: It resolved the error, but I'm getting an empty icon as if the source isn't correct.

Answer (score 3):

OpenWeatherMap's site explains how to display icons:

> https://openweathermap.org/weather-conditions

The following should work:

```js
<img src={`https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${props.icon}.png`} alt="cloud" />
```

Comment: As the answer above demonstrates, you need to specify the absolute path to the icon. The API will only return the weather condition code. You need to build the URL; the JSON response is not HATEOAS. The `Weather` component's `icon` prop should be a three-digit alpha-numeric code.

Comment: Thank you for your respone. "This is how i fix my bug " useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${search}&appid=1769e69d20183ccd0c32ac3215db1d40&units=metric`
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        setData(json);
        if (json.weather && json.weather.length > 0) {
          setIcon(json.weather[0].icon + ".png");
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }, [search]);"  {props.icon && <img src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${props.icon}`} alt="cloud" />}"

Comment: Since this answered your question, accept this as the answer and close as complete.

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Presumably this happens here:

```
let icon = data.weather[0].icon + ".png";
```

What is `data`?  It's an empty array:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

Arrays, empty or otherwise, have no property called `weather`.  Did you mean to read the first *element* of the array?  For example:

```
let icon = data[0].weather[0].icon + ".png";
```

Though even then you'd need [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), since the array is initially empty:

```
let icon = data[0]?.weather[0].icon + ".png";
```

You can include optional chaining any time you are accessing a property/index which may not exist.  Keep in mind of course that `icon` would then be something unexpected, such as `"null.png"` or `"undefined.png"`.

You could also set it to some default and conditionally override it.  For example:

```
let icon = "default.png";
if (data.length > 0) {
  icon = data[0].weather[0].icon + ".png";
}
```

Of course, all of this depends entirely on what `data` actually contains.  You initialize it as an array, but then the line of code we're talking about here assumed it was an object.  Which is it?

You'll need to know the structure of your data in order to use that data.  But any way you look at it, how you use it needs to support both the initial (empty) state *and* the later state in which the data is populated.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response and detailed explanation. I am very grateful. I hope i can solve my problem now.

Answer (score 0):

Your weather component should be set up in such a way that is models the response data.When accessing props, you can use object destructuring to access inner-properties.

Here is an example of weather for the city of New York:

```json
{
  "coord": { "lon": -74.006, "lat": 40.7143 },
  "weather": [{
    "id": 804,
    "main": "Clouds",
    "description": "overcast clouds",
    "icon": "04d"
  }],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 7.91,
    "feels_like": 5.37,
    "temp_min": 5.9,
    "temp_max": 10.27,
    "pressure": 1006,
    "humidity": 52
  },
  "visibility": 10000,
  "wind": { "speed": 4.12, "deg": 280 },
  "clouds": { "all": 100 },
  "dt": 1710943746,
  "sys": {
    "type": 2,
    "id": 2008101,
    "country": "US",
    "sunrise": 1710932317,
    "sunset": 1710976081
  },
  "timezone": -14400,
  "id": 5128581,
  "name": "New York",
  "cod": 200
}
```

In the component below, I memoized the `<img>` elements `src` attribute. This will update any time the incoming `src` changes. This is similar to a `useEffect`.

```js
import { useMemo } from React;

const IMG_PATH = 'https://openweathermap.org/img/wn';

const Weather = (props) => {
  const { data } = props;
  const { name, weather: [{ description, icon, main }] } = data;
  const imgSrc = useMemo(() => `${IMG_PATH}/${icon}.png`, [icon])
  return (
    <div className="weather">
      <h3>{name}</h3>
      <img src={imgSrc} alt={description} />
      <span>{main}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Weather;
```

#### Demo

Here is a full (working) demo below.

Just enter a city name into the input and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or press the "Submit" button.

```js
const { Fragment, useCallback, useEffect, useMemo, useRef, useState } = React;

const API_URL = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather';
const API_KEY = '1769e69d20183ccd0c32ac3215db1d40';
const IMG_PATH = 'https://openweathermap.org/img/wn';

const Weather = (props) => {
  const { data } = props;
  const {
    name,
    main: { temp, feels_like, temp_min, temp_max },
    wind: { speed, deg },
    weather: [{ description, icon, main }]
  } = data;
  const imgSrc = useMemo(() => `${IMG_PATH}/${icon}@2x.png`, [icon])
  return (
    <div className="weather flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-2">
      <h3 className="weather-city text-4xl">{name}</h3>
      <div className="weather-info flex gap-4">
        <div className="weather-temp flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
          <div className="weather-temp-range flex items-center justify-center gap-2 text-sm">
            <span className="flex gap-1">
              LO: 
              <span className="temp">{temp_min}</span>
            </span>
            <span className="flex gap-1">
              HI:
              <span className="temp">{temp_max}</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div className="weather-temp-now flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-2">
            <span className="temp text-5xl">{temp}</span>
            <span className="flex gap-1">
              Like:
              <span className="temp">{feels_like}</span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="weather-condition flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
          <img src={imgSrc} alt={description} />
          <span>{main}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const SearchForm = (props) => {
  const { searchRef, setWeatherData } = props;
  const [city, setCity] = useState();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (city) {
      fetch(`${API_URL}?q=${city}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => setWeatherData(data))
        .catch((error) => console.error(error));
    } else {
      setWeatherData(null);
    }
  }, [city]);

  const searchWeather = useCallback((event) => {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent navigation
    setCity(searchRef.current.value);
  }, [searchRef]);
  
  return (
    <form
      className="search-form flex items-center gap-2"
      name="weather-search"
      onSubmit={searchWeather}
    >
      <label className="bold" htmlFor="city-input">City:</label>
      <input
        type="search"
        id="city-input"
        name="city"
        placeholder="Enter a city name"
        ref={searchRef}
      />
      <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  const searchRef = useRef();
  const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState(null);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <SearchForm
        searchRef={searchRef}
        setWeatherData={setWeatherData}
      />
      <hr className="w-full" />
      {weatherData ? (
        <Weather data={weatherData} />
      ) : (
        <div className="italic">No weather found</div>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))
  .render(<App />);
```

```css
.temp:after {
  content: '°C';
}

/* Tailwind classes */
.w-full { width: 100%; }
.flex { display: flex; }
.flex-col { flex-direction: column; }
.flex-row { flex-direction: row; }
.items-center { align-items: center; }
.justify-center { justify-content: center; }
.p-1 { padding: 0.25rem; }
.p-2 { padding: 0.5rem; }
.p-3 { padding: 0.75rem; }
.p-4 { padding: 1rem; }
.gap-1 { gap: 0.25rem; }
.gap-2 { gap: 0.5rem; }
.gap-3 { gap: 0.75rem; }
.gap-4 { gap: 1rem; }
.text-xs { font-size: 0.75rem; line-height: 1rem; }
.text-sm { font-size: 0.875rem; line-height: 1.25rem; }
.text-base { font-size: 1rem; line-height: 1.5rem; }
.text-lg { font-size: 1.125rem; line-height: 1.75rem; }
.text-xl { font-size: 1.25rem; line-height: 1.75rem; }
.text-2xl { font-size: 1.5rem; line-height: 2rem; }
.text-3xl { font-size: 1.875rem; line-height: 2.25rem; }
.text-4xl { font-size: 2.25rem; line-height: 2.5rem; }
.text-5xl { font-size: 3rem; line-height: 1; }
.text-6xl { font-size: 3.75rem; line-height: 1; }
.text-7xl { font-size: 4.5rem; line-height: 1; }
.text-8xl { font-size: 6rem; line-height: 1; }
.text-9xl { font-size: 8rem; line-height: 1; }
.bold { font-weight: bold; }
.italic { font-style: italic; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="root" class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center p-4"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms to get Icon from data please make following changes in **App component**

```
 let icon =  `https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${data[0].weather[0].icon}.png`;
```